# Are " How to do?" and "What to do?" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Are " How to do?" and "What to do?" grammatically correct?

For example:
A - I left your book in the school today.
B - How to do ? OR What to do?

Comment: Are you from Malaysia or Singapore by any chance? I am aware that these are idioms in Straits English. As they tend to be used variously Ihey substitute for various things in standard English, In the example you give, possibly they mean "How did you do that?", and "What can I do about it?".

Comment: They are grammatically correct as phrases, but not idiomatic as complete sentences.

Comment: Hi, It's my helper from Philippines that kept on saying this phrase in front of my kids. I always thought a better way to say this  should be - What should I do? What can I do?

Comment: "What to do?" is perfectly idiomatic for "What should we do about this situation?" although it's old-fashioned. It doesn't mean "What shall we do today?" I've never heard "How to do?" used similarly though.

Comment: Well I wasn't to far away geographically, was I. But I'm interested in @Andrew Leach's comment. Yes, I believe they are both old-fashioned English, which may explain their continued use in some parts of the world today.

Comment: 'What to do?' is idiomatic. I've never heard of 'How to do?' But you should use "are", not "is" in your question title  since you're asking about more than one thing.

Comment: He told me what to do, but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Also see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101345/is-a-question-beginning-with-how-to-grammatically-correct

Answer (score 1):

*What to do?* is the correct option here.

The interrogative pronoun is here used as the direct object of the infinitive *to do*. A listener makes the necessary insertion: *What [is there] to do?*

Examining the other option, one sees that *how* is an interrogative adverb, but as the inquirer is asking what there is to do, not how something is to be done, this option does not fit here.

Note that NEITHER OPTION IS A COMPLETE SENTENCE.