# Is 'what to do' grammatically incorrect?

Tags: grammar

I have been given to understand that the sentence 'After waking up, she lay on bed thinking of what to do' is grammatically incorrect. The phrase 'what to do' should be replaced with 'what she should do'. So I'm curious about the validity of the said phrase now. Is it incorrect in all contexts?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with thinking of what to do. As far as "lay on bed," it's usually 'lay in bed' or 'lay on the bed.'

Comment: How does it differ from *She lay in bed thinking of what to say*? It doesn't. And using *what to do* instead of *what to say* is fine.

Comment: There's an expression "What to do?" which may seem ungrammatical, since it  lacks a finite verb. But it is considered idiomatic and grammatical. See the poorly worded  [Is " How to do?" and "What to do?" grammatically correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/375089/is-how-to-do-and-what-to-do-grammatically-correct)