# Is the sentence "What to do?" very old fashioned idiomatic English, or is it simply ungrammatical?

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis, archaicisms

On a foreign-language-learning forum there is a question that's given the English translation "What to do?"

My impression is that that's an example of very old fashioned English. Maybe something I'd expect in Shakespeare or at least a snooty upper class character in an old black-and-white movie.

Or am I mistaken and it's just a simple bad translation into an ungrammatical sentence lacking a main verb?

**References:**

- [A Spanish-English forum thread on Duolingo about "What to do"](https://www.duolingo.com/comment/18212651) in which some native English speakers take issue with it.
- *(I'm still looking for the original Duolingo thread which inspired me to ask this question, which was in a Chinese-English forum there...)*

At Mari-Lou's suggestion, here are some of the comments *against*. There are also comments *for*, which I'm not listing. You can scan through the thread if interested:

- Not at all common without a subject. More common: What am I doing?
- It may be heard in the UK, but it is not common. In context, it would probably be understood. But from a native speaker, it would sound archaic and peculiar.
- Native speakers in the US never say this!
- I have never heard anyone say What to do? in English
- "What to do?" Makes no sense as an English sentence.
- This is not a widely accepted way to express oneself in English.
- In English " To do what? or Do what! would be normal but not "What to do?" as a question is not correct in my opinion.
- I don't agree with Duolingo's translation on this one. In Spanish you can ask "Que hacer?", but in English "What to do?" is not a grammatically correct question.
- "What to do?" sounds like a mistake a Spanish-speaking person would make at an early stage of learning English.
- I certainly recognise what you say, but it doesn't sound like English as I speak it.
- Does any english speaker actually say "what to do?" I definitely don't

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is " How to do?" and "What to do?" grammatically correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/375089/is-how-to-do-and-what-to-do-grammatically-correct)

Answer (score 4):

It's at least idiomatic.  It's also often rhetorical: "I was walking along and found a bag of money.  What to do?  I could call the police, but no one is around..."

Comment: I feel I have to downvote this answer purely because the example usage is neither syntactically valid nor idiomatic. Native speakers don't randomly switch from past tense ***I was walking*** to present tense ***no-one is around***.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> (1) *What to do?* is not a sentence; there's no subject, for one thing. (2) The construction is not particularly archaic, although *wh*-infinitives have been around for a long time. They're still widely used. What they are isn't so much archaic or formal as it is **formulaic**. That is, everything is taken for granted and/or given in the context, so out of context they make no sense.

It may not be immediately clear to everyone why John said that there’s no subject in *What to do?*. I imagine some people are thinking that the *wh-* word there is the subject, but it’s not. It’s actually the object of that infinitive clause. Imagine a book title like *Whom to call?* There it’s clearly acting as the object of the verb *call*. If the answer is *him*.

- I don't know whom to call.
- Whom to call?
- Him.
- I’ll call him.

So it’s an object there.

That’s not to say that infinitive clauses cannot have subjects; they can do so, but this is not one of those cases. Examples of infinitive clause with an actual subject is:

- For her to call him that night was all he had ever hoped for.
- I need her to call me.

Just as not all sentences are questions, not all questions are sentences. That doesn’t make them ungrammatical. They simply aren’t sentences, since all sentences have a subject and a finite verb. When you have a *wh-* word plus an infinitive ending in an utterance ending with a question mark, you have a question. Any utterance that ends with a question mark is a question: it’s one inviting an answer. And not all answers are sentences either. They’re still answers.

> Question: Ready?
>
> Answer: Ready.